# valor Issuer de un certificado en c#

Tags: c#

Estimados.
Estoy extrayendo la propiedad Issuer de un certificado digital para luego firmar un archivo el asunto es que en c# me arroja esto

C=CO, L="BOGOTÁ, D.C.", STREET=Carrera 21 A No 124 - 55 Oficina 303. https://www.gse.com.co/direccion, OU=http://www.gse.com.co, T=AC GSE S.A., O=GESTION DE SEGURIDAD ELECTRONICA S.A., E=ca@gse.com.co, SERIALNUMBER=NIT 9002042728, CN=SUB001 AC GSE S.A., Description=Certificado Subordinada 001 AC GSE S.A.

pero el validador de firmas aparentemente me lo invalida porque lo quiere asi(creo que esta en java) :

C=CO,L=BOGOTÁ\, D.C.,STREET=Carrera 21 A No 124 - 55 Oficina 303. https://www.gse.com.co/direccion,OU=http://www.gse.com.co,2.5.4.12=#0c0b41432047534520532e412e,O=GESTION DE SEGURIDAD ELECTRONICA S.A.,1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#160d6361406773652e636f6d2e636f,2.5.4.5=#130e4e49542039303032303432373238,CN=SUB001 AC GSE S.A.,2.5.4.13=#0c27436572746966696361646f205375626f7264696e616461203030312041432047534520532e412e

la pregunta es como podria obtenerlo de la segunda forma.

Gracias